# Ошибка при билде на устройство

Tags: ios, unity3d, xcode

Раньше работал с андроидом. Сделал игру. Интегрировал  файербейс аналитику, Гугл рекламу, фейсбук  аналитику и фейсбук рекламу

Сейчас пытаюсь сбилдить её на iOS

Без проблем собрал проект xcode не проводил никаких настроек в нем. Только скачал провижен профайл для команды(персональной)

При билде на устройство выдает ошибку

```
ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/razrabotcik/Documents/Builds/TestBuil5/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
ld: Linking globals named 'fbad_Cocos2DGetGLViewController': symbol multiply defined! for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Гуглил подобное. Пишет что где то есть похожая переменная или функция которая создана в разных местах

Я пробовал искать такое название по проекту, но ничего не нашел
Что тут можно сделать ?

Запускал проект через воркспейс

Comment: Как именно Вы искали? Некоторые  способы поиска могут игнорировать строки между директивами `#if #endif`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский используя  shift + command + F

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский  или есть другой метод?